# Backup SQL Server DB from Windows Application not hosted on the SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

There are many examples available that provide SMO solutions to backing up an SQL database and I have one that works.

My scenario though requires me to backup an SQL database from a Windows Application on a machine that is connected to a network.

The problem is with the server name...Every time I run the below code I get the error "Backup failed for 'ServerName'."

It obviously cannot find the server. My class runs when I run the code on the server (and also on my local machine).

How do I connect to server?

My code is below:

```
public void BackupDB(string database, string databasename)
    {

        // Check if file exists - if so delete it...We don't want multiple backups kept.
        if (File.Exists(databasename) == true)
        {
            File.Delete(databasename);
        }

        Server srv = new Server("My SERVER NAME");

        Backup bkpDBFull = new Backup();


        /* Specify whether you want to back up database or files or log */
        bkpDBFull.Action = BackupActionType.Database;

        /* Specify the name of the database to back up */
        bkpDBFull.Database = database;

        /*  backup on the file system */
        bkpDBFull.Devices.AddDevice(databasename, DeviceType.File); 
        bkpDBFull.BackupSetName = "Database Backup";
        bkpDBFull.BackupSetDescription = "Database - Full Backup";

        /* You can specify the expiration date for your backup data
         * after that date backup data would not be relevant */
        //bkpDBFull.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(10);

        /* You can specify Initialize = false (default) to create a new
         * backup set which will be appended as last backup set on the media. You
         * can specify Initialize = true to make the backup as first set on the
         * medium and to overwrite any other existing backup sets if the all the
         * backup sets have expired and specified backup set name matches with
         * the name on the medium */
        bkpDBFull.Initialize = false;

        /* Wiring up events for progress monitoring */
        progbar1.Value = 0;
        progbar1.Maximum = 100;
        progbar1.Value = 10;
        bkpDBFull.PercentComplete += new PercentCompleteEventHandler(PercentCompleteEventHandler);
        bkpDBFull.PercentCompleteNotification = 10;

        //bkpDBFull.Complete += Backup_Completed;

        /* SqlBackup method starts to take back up
         * You can also use SqlBackupAsync method to perform the backup
         * operation asynchronously */
        try
        {
            bkpDBFull.SqlBackup(srv);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return;
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Backup Complete");

        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: I don't see where you define to **which file** the backup should go! Also: if you run this on a remote server - mind you the backup file will be placed **on that remote server's** file system - ***not*** onto your local PC's disk! You need to be aware of this and make sure the path you define on that remote server's file system exists, and your identity running this code can write to that location ....

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the connection from other computers in your SQL server. This description will guide you through the process:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345343(v=sql.105).aspx